# "Error: array subscript is not an integer" in C with pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I suppose this is one of the most common errors asked, but in this case I know it has something to do with the use of pointers:

```
float  *interpolar_renglon(float val,float col,float **M,float r1,float r2)
{  
    float *l=malloc(6*sizeof(float));  
    l[0]=interpolar(val, M[r1][col], M[r1][0], M[r2][col], M[r2][0]);  
    l[1]=interpolar(val, M[r1][col], M[r1][1], M[r2][col], M[r2][1]);  
    l[2]=interpolar(val, M[r1][col], M[r1][2], M[r2][col], M[r2][2]);  
    l[3]=interpolar(val, M[r1][col], M[r1][3], M[r2][col], M[r2][3]);  
    l[4]=interpolar(val, M[r1][col], M[r1][4], M[r2][col], M[r2][4]);  
    l[5]=interpolar(val, M[r1][col], M[r1][5], M[r2][col], M[r2][5]);  
    return (l);
}
```

This is a function in my program, it is supposed to take a certain float value and two lines of 6 numbers from an array M, and it takes these values and sends them to a different function which returns them to an array l of size 6. The function will return array l.

The problem here is it sends me this error:

> "Error: array subscript is not an integer"
>   which I know is because the subscripts in the l array that should be of type int, but since this array was declared as a pointer I don't know how to solve this problem since I´m practically new to the pointers.

If someone could tell me how the declaration should be or how I could fix this problem I would be really thankful, also if could explain a little the answer I would appreciate it.

Ps. Sorry for the bad english, it isn't my natural language, I'd also appreciate corrections in the writing.

Comment: Good question. I think converting r1 and r2 to integers before used for indexing would help...

Comment: Should `r1` and `r2` even be `float`s?  Do they ever need a non-integer value (which wouldn't make sense as an array index)?

Comment: Use `int` (or `size_t` or integer type) for `r1` , `r2` and `col`.

Comment: i think the problem is that you are returning an integer while the function needs to return a <code>float*</code>

Comment: thank you, it actually worked, I really don't know why those variables were 'float' initially

Comment: @Dmitri: Fun fact: in GLSL, a `sampler2DArray` must be indexed by floats. This causes no end of problems. Be glad C is sane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you declare `r1` and `col` as `float` arguments to the function, so when you try to do `M[r1][col]`, you get the error "subscript is not an integer" because your subscripts are `float`, not integer.